# Entity Framework 6 Core - Reference by multiple columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

So I have this table that stores wikipedia pages for given entities:

WikipediaDomain

```
public class WikipediaDomain{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public int EntityId {get;set;}
  public int EntityType {get;set;}
  public string PageName {get;set;}
}
```

Now I have Countries and cities that have wikipedia pages.

```
Public class CountryDomain{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public ICollection<WikipediaDomain> WikipediaPages {get;set;}
}
```

```
Public class CityDomain{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public ICollection<WikipediaDomain> WikipediaPages {get;set;}
}
```

Is there a way with EF code first I can use the `ModelBuilder` to have 1 table for the Wikipedia pages and can reference them from the other domains?
So in `WikipediaDomain` that `EntityId` is the reference of the country or city id and that `EntityType` is the distractor between the two?

Comment: How flexible are you with your table structure? Is it possible to follow the [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance) pattern for your `Country` and `City`? (e.g. maybe have both inherit from `Place`). That would save you from having to keep track of the EntityType in your wikipedia domain.

Answer (score 0):

First, "domain" is the wrong term, so just eliminate it from all your type names.  And no, EF requires each navigation property to use a separate foreign key property.

You can use a single WikipediaPage entity, but it will have FKs to each related entity.  Alternatively you can model linking entities if you don't want the FKs on separate tables.